# Библиотеки php для yii2 на os x

Tags: php, yii2, macos, apache2

Добрый день, инсталлирую на локальный сервер(php-7.1/apache-2.4/os x high sierra) yii2. Запускаю скрипт на проверку требований

```
php requirements.php
```

Получаю

```
Yii Application Requirement Checker

This script checks if your server configuration meets the requirements
for running Yii application.
It checks if the server is running the right version of PHP,
if appropriate PHP extensions have been loaded, and if php.ini file settings are correct.

Check conclusion:
-----------------

PHP version: OK

Reflection extension: OK

PCRE extension: OK

SPL extension: OK

Ctype extension: OK

MBString extension: OK

OpenSSL extension: OK

Intl extension: WARNING!!!
Required by: Internationalization support
Memo: PHP Intl extension 1.0.2 or higher is required when you want to use advanced parameters formatting
        in Yii::t(), non-latin languages with Inflector::slug(),
        IDN-feature of
        EmailValidator or UrlValidator or the yii\i18n\Formatter class.

ICU version: WARNING!!!
Required by: Internationalization support
Memo: ICU 49.0 or higher is required when you want to use # placeholder in plural rules
        (for example, plural in

        Formatter::asRelativeTime()) in the yii\i18n\Formatter class. Your current ICU version is (ICU is missing).

ICU Data version: WARNING!!!
Required by: Internationalization support
Memo: ICU Data 49.1 or higher is required when you want to use # placeholder in plural rules
        (for example, plural in

        Formatter::asRelativeTime()) in the yii\i18n\Formatter class. Your current ICU Data version is (ICU Data is missing).

Fileinfo extension: OK

DOM extension: OK

IPv6 support: OK

PDO extension: OK

PDO SQLite extension: OK

PDO MySQL extension: OK

PDO PostgreSQL extension: OK

Memcache extension: WARNING!!!
Required by: MemCache

GD PHP extension with FreeType support: WARNING!!!
Required by: Captcha
Memo: GD extension should be installed with FreeType support in order to be used for image CAPTCHA.

ImageMagick PHP extension with PNG support: WARNING!!!
Required by: Captcha
Memo: Either GD PHP extension with FreeType support or ImageMagick PHP extension with PNG support is required for image CAPTCHA.

Expose PHP: WARNING!!!
Required by: Security reasons
Memo: "expose_php" should be disabled at php.ini

PHP allow url include: OK

PHP mail SMTP: OK

------------------------------------------
Errors: 0   Warnings: 7   Total checks: 23
```

Понимаю, что нехватает библиотек для php, но не могу разобраться как их правильно установить можно в mac os.
Решается ли данный вопрос подключением нужных директив с помощью php.ini? или же все таки надо качать дополнительно библиотеки?

Answer (score 0):

Доставьте нужные либы и все. Первая строчка в гугле:

```
brew install php70-intl
```